# Dropwizard/Jersey resource handler not correctly parsing json data

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

I'm working on a Dropwizard/Jersey backend. In one particular case, the data sent is not being parsed into the appropriate object. If I add @NotEmpty to a string field, I get a 422 error. Here is the java code:

```java
static final class UpdateGroupParams {
  int itemgroupId;
  String name;
  String displayName;
  int priority;
  List<Integer> itemIds;
}

@PUT
@Path("{groupId: [0-9]+}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response saveGroup(@NotNull @PathParam("groupId") int groupId, UpdateGroupParams params) {
```

Using this request:

```
curl -X PUT -H 'AlliedAuth: xxx' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"itemgroupId":1017,"priority":2,"name":"easter","displayName":"Easter","itemIds":[1007,1004,1006,1002,1005]}' -v http://localhost:8080/v1/siteadmin/groups/1017
```

A breakpoint inside saveGroup() shows that params's values are all 0 or null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that UpdateGroupParams did not have a constructor. Adding the lombok annotation @AllArgsConstructor fixed the problem.